# In wordpress add_action, javascript alert works only in init why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

```
add_action( 'init', 'init_fire' );

 function init_fire()
    {
          echo  "<script>
                    alert('init');
                </script>";

    }
```

the above code alert works , but wp_login, wp_logout javascript alert not working.

```
add_action( 'wp_logout','logout_event');

function logout_event() {
   echo  "<script>
            alert('logout');
         </script>";

}
```

above code alert not working. If I give php exit then it is working but shows blank page. Please help me to alert in wp_logout without php exit.

Comment: where is add_action() function ?

Comment: add_action() are the hooks that the WordPress core launches at specific points during execution, or when specific events occur

Answer (score 0):

Can check below code

```
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_external_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_external_after_logout()
{
  echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert('logout');
         </script>";
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. php exit redirect to "http://localhost/exams/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=bc6e4d9da2" this url and show blank page. But alert working.

Comment: Ok you can remove the exit(); and can check this as resolved

Comment: No , now alert not working. This is working perfect in add_action( 'init', 'init_fire' ); but other hooks not working :-(

Comment: I am using this code in /var/www/html/exams/wp-content/themes/startertheme/functions.php in wordpress

Comment: echo  "<script>
                    window.analytics.track('type', {
                        'Event':'init'
                        });
                </script>";   I need the above script should work